# Performance of OpenLaszlo based AIR apps on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, mobile, air, openlaszlo

Has anyone tried to compile an OpenLaszlo application as a mobile app for Android or iOS, using a recent version of the Adobe AIR SDK? Is the performance sufficient for apps not requiring a lot of computing power?

Comment: When I first tried the AIR for Android deployment back in 2010, performance was not that good. Initializing a Google Map (Flash API) took about six seconds on a Google Nexus One phone. I haven't tested the newer versions of AIR, but heard that the performance is much better now.

Comment: I've seen the demo videos by Adobe on Youtube, where they show the performance improvements of Adobe AIR 3.0 for iOS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPHATCbnHE0  
But do these improvements apply to OpenLaszlo as well, since I don't think that OpenLaszlo uses any of the Stage3D features? With [Adobe's Starling framework](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/introducing_Starling.html) it should be possible to get much better performance, but that would require an OpenLaszlo Air runtime optimized for Starling.

Answer (score 1):

I compile my OpenLaszlo apps to HTML5/DHTML using a recent OpenLaszlo 5.0 from nightly builds (not released yet) . I don't use Adobe Air so I am sorry I can't answer to that, but in my experience performance degrades in direct proportion to how many DIVs the application is spawning. You need to reuse views/components you create, and yes load time is significant because OL apps are quite big. If it is an existing app, it might be worth doing. But for a new app I would suggest a more proven framework and component set like JQuery mobile.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. That's what I already guessed. The new DHTML optimization Frank Guo did on the OpenLaszlo kernel might help, since he managed to optimize the <div> structure for some browser in DHTML runtime. Not sure if that's true for the iPad as well. Btw, your profile page uses a wrong URL for your homepage: http://www.www,poodll.com/